# VLOOKUP returning wrong row

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-vlookup

I have a fairly simple lookup table:

[image]

The formula I have in B6 is:

```
=VLOOKUP(A6,C1:D4,2)
```

So I would expect it to return 1, not 4?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are omitting the sorted flag, which then defaults to *TRUE* thus making it ignore the exact match.

Quoting Google Help:

> It’s recommended to set is_sorted to *FALSE*. If set to *FALSE*, an exact match is returned. If there are multiple matching values, the content of the cell corresponding to the first value found is returned, and *#N/A* is returned if no such value is found.

Check this image out:

[image]

Hope that helps, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

you miss the 4th vlookup parameter. use this:

```
=VLOOKUP(A6, C1:D4, 2, 0)
```

or:

```
=VLOOKUP(A6, C1:D4, 2, )
```

or:

```
=VLOOKUP(A6, C1:D4, 2, FALSE)
```

to get **exact match**

Answer (score 0):

```
VLOOKUP(search_key, range, index, [is_sorted])
```

Where

```
is_sorted - [optional]

Indicates whether the column to be searched (the first column of the 
   specified range) is sorted, in which case the closest match for 
   search_key will be returned.
```

so

```
=VLOOKUP(A6,C1:D4,2) ==> will give you 4, because is_sorted=1, sorted of the              
                         column that to be search. If you change A6=Monthly,
                         it will give you 2
```

to give you as is, no sorted, so you assign the is_sorted to 0

```
=VLOOKUP(A6,C1:D4,2,0)
```